# How to set innerHTML jsx format

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I given this code:

```
render() {
  console.log(this.props, 'ey');
  const var1 = "<div className={{blahblah}} style={{width: '10px'}}>{textvar}</div>"


  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `${var1}` }}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Of course that's just an example, but the `var1` should be a big chunk of html file in jsx format, however doing that one renders them as they are and doesn't convert them to regular html.

I also tried setting innerHTML via refs on componentDidMount but same problem happens.

this is what it should look like when it renders:

```
<div class="blahblah style="width: 10px"}}>the variable text</div>
```

Any help would greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: the real question is "why". As "of course, just an example" this is really not good enough - what are you *actually* doing? Because quite often the solution is "don't use HTML, get your data, and inject it into a component properly".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Because the client want to do it like this, they want to store it somewhere, a couple of versions of the page, and just update those files/data without having to push another commit. You know that feeling when you tried to argue to the client but still ends up doing what they wanted? :D

Comment: If the client needs that much flexibility you are going to end up building the React framework for them and they will need to learn to program in React.... I've been down this road and you are opening a can of worms.

Comment: I know that feeling, and I started telling my clients "no", then talking with them to figure out what they need at the site level, not what they want at the code level. The code level is not theirs to decide, unless they're going to write it themselves. Putting HTML on a page is not "storage", your *app* is the storage, with different levels. In-memory, localStorage, remote db, etc. Also "just update those files/data without having to push another commit" makes no sense. *Any* static data should be revision controlled, and *any* change to that is a commit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to do this to use [ES6 interpolated string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (inaccurately called template literals by the spec):

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `${var1}` }}>
```

But this would be simpler:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: var1 }}>
```

However, in your string for the inner html, you may want to use an interpolated string literal if what you want is to use the values of the `blahblah` and `textvar` variables. Note you need to use `class` instead of `className` since React will just set the inner html rather than treat it as JSX and `className` is only for JSX.

```
const var1 = `<div class=${blahblah}>${textvar}</div>`;
```

If you are using a class, no need to also use the style keyword. Just set the width in your CSS.

You can see a [working example of the above on CodePen](http://codepen.io/tchaffee/pen/bWBLpp).

Comment: are there any other ways? because yes I already considered this solution before however it there's a lot of limitations like, what if I'm trying to set a variable classname? or what If I'll call a function / bind an event.

Comment: There are other ways. Explain in your question exactly what you are trying to achieve. Or create new stackoverflow questions if you have several scenarios you want to understand.